# How to hide some controls in LIstview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView with some controls inside it. Now the situation is that I want to hide few controls on a particular "listview Item" ..

Answer (score 0):

You can either do that in your `getView()` or iterate through the listview items and in that particular item, use the parent view to do operations on the child views. If you do the iteration make a use of `AsyncTask`.

Something like this:

```
   private class UI extends AsyncTask <View, String, View>
     {
         public View viewItem=null;
         public UI(View v)
         {
             this.viewItem=v;
         }
        @Override
        protected View doInBackground(View... arg0) {

            return viewItem;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            for(int i = 0; i  <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
            {
                if(listView.getChildAt(i)!= null)
                {
                    (listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    (listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.remove)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(View result) {

            ((Button)result.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button)result.findViewById(R.id.remove)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

     }
```

Comment: where should I place this... In activity or in adapter

Comment: In your activity as private class. The just create object from this class and call it .execute(""); You call this class every time item is clicked. If don't want to do this way, you can check in your adapter (getview() method)

Comment: Thanx for showing your concern..I thought you didn't get what I meant .. let suppose there are 5 controls on a single Listview Item and 3 controls are required to hide for some particular Item position. Can you help me on this

Comment: Make test in the for loop if(i==myPosition) hide this and this button :D myPosition holds the particular position you said. Also you can do this in getView(). also with same test.

Comment: As you said ""You call this class every time item is clicked"" I want to hide those controls before listview is displayed/drawn.

Comment: Well, then you do that in `getView()` method while list is populating you hide the controls.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1759/discussion-between-ahmed-saud-and-nikolamkd)